# Grep partial string only

Tags: grep

I got a file. This file contains strings like

```
sdnfasdnbfas;jdfnba;ldjfnb;asdf[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1] adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf
sdnfasdnbfas;jdfnba;ldjfnb;asdf[MESG: I NEED THIS: 2] adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf
sdnfasdnbfas;jdfnba;ldjfnb;asdf[MESG: I NEED THIS: 3] adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

How can I use "grep" to gain an output like:

```
MESG: I NEED THIS: 1
MESG: I NEED THIS: 2
MESG: I NEED THIS: 3
```

Comment: `grep` is not the best tool for this. It's an awk problem.

Comment: Can you be more pricise please?

Answer (score 1):

read up on regex:

```
$ echo 'sdnfasdnbfas;jdfnba;ldjfnb;asdf[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1] adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf' | grep -Eo '\[.*\]'
[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]
$
```

Comment: I will try. 10x. I will come back with an answer.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that i use "-ash" not classical shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fast help. Unfortunately I`m running -ash and a small workaround was necessary. I fix my problem by running:

```
grep -o "\w*[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]\w*"
```

Now I will like to give something back to the community. 
Because I fix my little problem, i will share a generic script to monitor a certain file after multiple strings and act accordingly.

```
## This is a generic script to monitor a file for multiple strings and
## act accordingly. 
while true                                                                                                                                      
do                                                                                                                                              
grep -o "\w*[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]\w*" /don/key | grep '[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]' &> /dev/null                                                                    
        if [ $? == 0 ];                                                                                                                         
                then                                                                                                                            
                        echo "matched 1"                                                                                                                 
                else                                                                                                                            
                        echo "not matched 1"                                                                                                    
fi                                                                                                                                              
grep -o "\w*[MESG: I NEED THIS: 2]\w*" /don/key | grep '[MESG: I NEED THIS: 2]' &> /dev/null                                                                    
        if [ $? == 0 ];                                                                                                                         
                then                                                                                                                            
                        echo "matched 2"                                                                                                           
                else                                                                                                                            
                        echo "not matched 2"                                                                                                    
fi                                                                                                                                              

grep -o "\w*[MESG: I NEED THIS: 3]\w*" /don/key | grep '[MESG: I NEED THIS: 3]' &> /dev/null                                                                    
        if [ $? == 0 ];                                                                                                                         
                then                                                                                                                            
                 echo "matched 3"                                                                                                                   
                else                                                                                                                            
                 echo "not matched 3"                                                                                                            
fi                                                                                                                                              

sleep 3                                                                                                                                         

done
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of the first `grep -o` in each pipeline. Why not just `if grep -qF '[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]'; then ...; else ...; fi`? Also note that `[...]` denotes a character class, i.e. `[I NEED THIS]` would match any (single) character in the set `I`, `N`, `E`, `D`, `T`, `H`, `S` and space.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [your own answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459613/116858), here is a suggestion:

```
for number in 1 2 3; do
    string="[MESG: I NEED THIS: $number]"

    if grep -qF "$string" /don/key; then
        printf 'Matched %d\n' "$number"
    else
        printf 'Did not match %d\n' "$number"
    fi
done
```

Note that if you want to match a fixed string (not a regular expression), you should use `-F` with `grep`.  If you don't use `-F`, you will have to escape any characters that are special in regular expressions (in this case, `[` and `]`).

The `-q` stops `grep` from producing any output. We're not interested in the output, only if it matches or not.

The regular expression `[MESG: I NEED THIS: 1]` matches exactly one character from the set of characters inside the `[...]`, which is not what you want.